# Calling event listeners from a separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added two click event listeners:

- `$(openGalleryDiv).click()` will show an `overflow: hidden` div with a slide animation
- `$(closeGalleryDiv).click()` will hide (`overflow:auto`) the opened div

Now the problem is that if I set the event listeners directly into the `index.php` page everything works fine, but if I set them into funcions in the `main.js` file (like below) calling the function `openCloseGallery.desktopEvents()` inside `index.php`, both events are fired when the page is loaded although no div is clicked.

Can someone explain me why?

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    openCloseGallery.desktopEvents();
});
```

main.js

```
var openCloseGallery = function () {
    function openCloseAnimation(action) {
        if (action) {               // 1 -> OPEN
            $(galleryDiv).parent().addClass('animate-open-gallery');
            $(superWrapperDiv).addClass('animate-close-superwrapper');
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        } else {                    // 0 -> CLOSE
            $(galleryDiv).parent().removeClass('animate-open-gallery').addClass('animate-close-gallery');
            $(superWrapperDiv).removeClass('animate-close-superwrapper').addClass('animate-open-superwrapper');
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        }
    }

    var desktopEvents = function () {
        $(openGalleryDiv).click(openCloseAnimation(true));
        $(closeGalleryDiv).click(openCloseAnimation(false));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function in the event listeners.  Try

```
    var desktopEvents = function () {
        $(openGalleryDiv).click(function(){ openCloseAnimation(true) });
        $(closeGalleryDiv).click(function(){ openCloseAnimation(false) });
    });
```

In your current code, it's passing the return of your function `openCloseAnimation(true/false)` instead of returning the function itself.

Comment: I tried also this way but it didn't work; under your suggestion I tried it again and now it works! Mistery. Thanks larz

Answer (score 1):

You are directly calling the method while passing as a callback. You should pass a callback to click method as follows

```
// This is directly calling openCloseAnimation method
$(openGalleryDiv).click(openCloseAnimation(true));

//  It should be inside callback
$(openGalleryDiv).click(function(){ openCloseAnimation(true) });
```